# How does the __call metamethod in Lua 5.1 actually work?

Tags: lua, call

I'm trying, as an exercise, to make a set implementation in Lua.  Specifically I want to take the simplistic set implementation of Pil2 11.5 and grow it up to include the ability to insert values, delete values, etc.

Now the obvious way to do this (and the way that works) is this:

```
Set = {}
function Set.new(l)
    local s = {}
    for _, v in ipairs(l) do
        s[v] = true
    end
    return s
end
function Set.insert(s, v)
    s[v] = true
end

ts = Set.new {1,2,3,4,5}
Set.insert(ts, 5)
Set.insert(ts, 6)

for k in pairs(ts) do
    print(k)
end
```

As expected I get the numbers 1 through 6 printed out.  But those calls to `Set.insert(s, value)` are really rather ugly.  I'd much rather be able to call something like `ts:insert(value)`.

My first attempt at a solution to this looked like this:

```
Set = {}
function Set.new(l)
    local s = {
        insert = function(t, v)
            t[v] = true
        end
    }
    for _, v in ipairs(l) do
        s[v] = true
    end
    return s
end

ts = Set.new {1,2,3,4,5}
ts:insert(5)
ts:insert(6)

for k in pairs(ts) do
    print(k)
end
```

This works mostly fine until you see what comes out of it:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
insert
```

Very obviously the insert function, which is a member of the set table, is being displayed.  Not only is this even uglier than the original `Set.insert(s, v)` problem, it's also prone to some serious trouble (like what happens if "insert" is a valid key someone is trying to enter?).  It's time to hit the books again.  What happens if I try this instead?:

```
Set = {}
function Set.new(l)
    local s = {}
    setmetatable(s, {__call = Set.call})
    for _, v in ipairs(l) do
        s[v] = true
    end
    return s
end
function Set.call(f)
    return Set[f]
end
function Set.insert(t, v)
    t[v] = true
end

ts = Set.new {1,2,3,4,5}
ts:insert(5)
ts:insert(6)

for k in pairs(ts) do
    print(k)
end
```

Now the way I'm reading this code is:

- When I call `ts:insert(5)`, the fact that `insert` doesn't exist to be called means that the `ts` metatable is going to be searched for `"__call"`.
- The `ts` metatable's `"__call"` key returns `Set.call`.
- Now `Set.call` is called with the name `insert` which causes it to return the `Set.insert` function.
- `Set.insert(ts, 5)` is called.

What's really happening is this:

```
lua: xasm.lua:26: attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        xasm.lua:26: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

And at this point I'm stumped.  I have absolutely no idea where to go from here.  I hacked around for an hour with varying degrees of increasingly desperate variations on this code but the end result is that I have nothing that works.  What undoubtedly obvious thing am I overlooking at this point?

Comment: Just wanna say I absolutely love your username

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Now the way I'm reading this code is:
>
> - When I call ts:insert(5), the fact that insert doesn't exist to be called means that the ts metatable is going to be searched for "__call".

There's your problem.  The `__call` metamethod is consulted when the *table itself* is called (ie, as a function):

```
local ts = {}
local mt = {}

function mt.__call(...)
    print("Table called!", ...)
end

setmetatable(ts, mt)

ts() --> prints "Table called!"
ts(5) --> prints "Table called!" and 5
ts"String construct-call" --> prints "Table called!" and "String construct-call"
```

Object-oriented colon-calls in Lua such as this:

```
ts:insert(5)
```

are merely syntactic sugar for

```
ts.insert(ts,5)
```

which is itself syntactic sugar for

```
ts["insert"](ts,5)
```

As such, the action that is being taken on `ts` is not a **call**, but an **index** (the *result* of `ts["insert"]` being what is called), which is governed by the `__index` metamethod.

The `__index` metamethod can be a table for the simple case where you want indexing to "fall back" to another table (note that it is the *value of the __index key* in the metatable that gets indexed and *not* the metatable itself):

```
local fallback = {example = 5}
local mt = {__index = fallback}
local ts = setmetatable({}, mt)
print(ts.example) --> prints 5
```

The `__index` metamethod as a function works similarly to the signature you expected with Set.call, except that it passes the table being indexed before the key:

```
local ff = {}
local mt = {}

function ff.example(...)
  print("Example called!",...)
end

function mt.__index(s,k)
  print("Indexing table named:", s.name)
  return ff[k]
end

local ts = {name = "Bob"}
setmetatable(ts, mt)
ts.example(5) --> prints "Indexing table named:" and "Bob",
              --> then on the next line "Example called!" and 5
```

For more information on metatables, consult [the manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8).

Comment: This is basically Zecc's answer upside-down with more intermediate example code.

Comment: May very well be, but I'm sold. :)

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for the pointer and the *extremely* detailed response.

Comment: Complete answer but yet easy to understand for a novice like me. Excellent!

Comment: Beautiful explanation; I was wondering how to implement JavaScript-style behaviour, where functions are a subtype of hashtables (and so can have properties accessed with the usual `table.key` syntax). *(The broader context is that I'm trying to make classes, and I like the `Car.staticProperty` notation of JavaScript, but prefer the Python-style `Car()` constructor notation without the `new` keyword.)* This answer's shown me I can simply use a table and give it a `__call` metamethod to achieve the same! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You said:

> Now the way I'm reading this code is:
>
> - When I call ts:insert(5), the fact that insert doesn't
>     exist to be called means that the ts metatable is going
>     to be searched for "__call".
> - The ts metatable's "__call" key returns Set.call.
> - Now Set.call is called with the name insert which causes
>     it to return the Set.insert function.
> - Set.insert(ts, 5) is called.

No, what happens is this:

- When `insert` isn't found directly in the `ts` object, Lua looks for `__index` in its metatable.

  - If it is there and it is a table, Lua will search for `insert` there.
  - If it is there and it is a function, it will call it with the original table (`ts` in this case) and the key being searched for (`insert`).
  - If it isn't there, which is the case, it is considered `nil`.

The error you're having is because you don't have `__index` set in your metatable, so you are effectively calling a `nil` value.

This can be solved by pointing `__index` to some table, namely `Set`, if you're going to store your methods there.

As for `__call`, it is used for when you call the object as a function. Ie:

```
Set = {}
function Set.new(l)
    local s = {}
    setmetatable(s, {__index=Set, __call=Set.call})
    for _, v in ipairs(l) do
        s[v] = true
    end
    return s
end
function Set.call(s, f)
    -- Calls a function for every element in the set
    for k in pairs(s) do
        f(k)
    end
end
function Set.insert(t, v)
    t[v] = true
end

ts = Set.new {1,2,3,4,5}
ts:insert(5)
ts:insert(6)

ts(print) -- Calls getmetatable(ts).__call(ts, print),
          -- which means Set.call(ts, print)

-- The way __call and __index are set,
-- this is equivalent to the line above
ts:call(print)
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what was wrong with the original code.

Comment: BTW, because I put the `call(s, f)` function in `Set` -- which is `getmetatable(ts).__index` -- you can also write `ts:call(print)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Set = {}
function Set.new(l)
    local s = {}
    setmetatable(s, {__index=Set})
    for _, v in ipairs(l) do
        s[v] = true
    end
    return s
end
function Set.call(f)
    return Set[f]
end
function Set.insert(t, v)
    t[v] = true
end

ts = Set.new {1,2,3,4,5}
ts:insert(5)
ts:insert(6)

for k in pairs(ts) do
    print(k)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I modified your first version and this version would offer the features I think you are looking for.

```
Set = {}
Set.__index = Set 

function Set:new(collection)
  local o = {}
  for _, v in ipairs(collection) do
    o[v] = true
  end 
  setmetatable(o, self)
  return o
end

function Set:insert(v)
  self[v] = true
end

set = Set:new({1,2,3,4,5})
print(set[1]) --> true
print(set[10]) --> nil
set:insert(10)
print(set[10]) --> true
```